# Iterations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, for 
**[p1,p2,p3]**=**[0.4,0.3,0.8]**, and k=2. The 2-subsets of 
{1,2,3}
and the corresponding probabilties that 
Xi
is one iff i
is in the subset are

{1,2} = 0.024 = **(0.4x0.3x(1-0.8))**

{1,3} = 0.224 = **(0.4x0.8x(1-0.3))**

{2,3} = 0.144 = **(0.3x0.8x(1-0.4))**

{1,2}=0.024

{1,3}=0.224

{2,3}=0.144
hence,

**P(X=k)=0.024+0.224+0.144=0.392.**

What will be the **python code** for this? I tried using itertools.combination but it 
showing **itertools.combinations object at 0x00000218F0129A48**

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: Just convert that into list.`list(your_combination_obj)`

Comment: I tried converting it to list . It shows float not iterable

Comment: If a = [p1,p2,p3], list(itertools.combinations(a,2)) will yield the combinations of p1,p2, p3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be clunky, but it does what you're looking for.

```
import itertools
a = [0.4,0.3,0.8]
l = list(itertools.combinations(a,len(a)-1))
print(l)
x = []
while l:
    b = l.pop()
    for item in a:
        if not item in b:
            multiply = 1
            for s in b:
                multiply = multiply * s
            x.append(multiply * (1 - item))
            print(x[-1])

print(sum(x))
```

Output:

```
0.144
0.22400000000000003
0.023999999999999994
0.392
```

Comment: Unfortunately it only works for a list of 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Edited to make it work with more than 3, I believe.

Comment: It does work but the output is wrong. because only multiplies the value of s[0]*s[1] and then multiplies this value with the number of remaining items

Comment: I'm not sure how it should be done at this point, does k need to change?

Comment: yes , K and p both can be variable .

Comment: Not sure if my last edit is correct or not, kinda out of my area of math.